# showing Triangle vertex cover is NP Hard

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, np-complete

> Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k$, is there a subset of vertices with size at most $k$ such that every triangle* in $G$ has at least one vertex contained in this set?
>
> *triangle: a set of three vertexes in which every vertex is connected by an edge to the other two vertexes

I need to prove that this problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard using known $\mathsf{NP}$-hard problem.
I thought of reduction from $\mathsf{3SAT}$ by converting the $\mathsf{3SAT}$ expression to a graph in which every clause is a triangle and every literal in the clause will be converted to a vertex.
I had a problem converting the other direction : given a graph $G = (V,E)$, I have to convert every triangle to a clause, but what about the other vertices not in a triangle?
Is the reduction from $\mathsf{3SAT}$ possible?

Comment: Why do you need to convert a graph into a CNF formula?  In proving NP-hardness by reduction from 3SAT, you need to show that if you could solve Triangle Vertex Cover in polynomial time, you could solve 3SAT in polynomial time too.  For that you need to translate a 3CNF formula to a graph in such a way that the formula is satisfiable *if and only if* the graph has a triangle vertex cover of a certain cardinality.  This is where you find the "bidirectionality," not in the construction of one object from the other.

Comment: I think you are referring to 3-clique. And did you mean at least ?

Comment: It looks like the question is are there $K/3$ 3-cliques in the graph G ?